# PHPMailer issue

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer for sending activation codes to users. As far as I know, that's best script for this purpose. Today noticed that, some users doesn't receive activation codes. But mailer return "Succesfully sent" message. Is there any chance that, phpmailer can't send to some mail servers? Or which is the best php script for sending mail via smtp authentification in your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not obvious that it is PHPMailer problem. It has connected to your smtp server and successfully sent the message. By *successfully* I mean that **your** server has accepted it. What happens next is a mystery and you have no control over it.

Few common reasons of undelivered mail:

- marked as SPAM by foreign server (advise users to check their spam folder)
- target mailbox does not exist (typos in username etc)
- user inbox is full and will not accept new mail
- mail queue on the server is quite big and it will take few minutes / hours to deliver

The best you can do is to advise users to keep their mailboxes clean, check their spam folder, retype email to prevent typos and offer a service for re-sending the activation email.

Comment: which one is better? swift or phpmailer?

Comment: the problem is, I tries with swift too. Foreign server gets email from gmail servers not from me. Searched in bulk, junk folder too. no new email

Answer (score 1):

I send registration and activation emails using [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) via Google Apps Mail (support@mydomain.com). It works like a charm, easy to setup, and has no delivery issues since it's using Google's servers. Check it out.

Comment: Tried swift too. Can't send to exact server